# Basic confusion with buffer overflow math

Tags: c, gdb, 32bit-64bit

I'm following along with a Youtube Computerphile buffer overflow tutorial to learn how it works. The tutorial says its in Kali, and I'm running Kali 64-bit to test it (I think he's running 32-bit).

He writes a simple program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char buffer[500];        
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Then after starting the program in GDB he runs:

`(gdb) run $(python -c 'print "\x41" * 506')`

and the result is a seg fault which shows that the return address was half overwritten with two 41's.

When I try to duplicate this, I need to change 506 to 522 in order to produce the same result. So my questions are:

1. Why does 506 only rewrite two bytes instead of three when he runs
   it?
2. Why do I need to write 522 bytes to overwrite 2 bytes in the return
       address? I think it has to do with him probably using 32-bit instead
       of 64-bit Kali, but I don't really understand how this difference
       adds up mathematically.
3. When I do `disassemble main` I see that after the function prologue is  the instruction `sub
   rsp, 0x210`, so it looks like buffer is allocated to 528 bytes. Why
   this number in particular (his instead subs 0x1f4 which is exactly 500) and how does it relate to the above where greater than 520 bytes is needed to start rewriting the instruction pointer?
4. What is happening in the range of writing [500,520] bytes where it's
   more than the buffer size, but not yet writing over top of the
   instruction pointer?

Comment: Perhaps the 32-bit version uses a 4-byte stack alignment whereas the 64-bit version uses an 8-byte stack alignment. 500 is divisible by 4, but not 8. The `buffer` would be padded with 4 bytes but this would result in 504 bytes. Not sure where the 520 is coming from.

Comment: Hmm is it possible that it's 500 padded with 4 to 504 then +16 to 520 because in between the buffer and the return address is the base pointer address?

Comment: Can you look at the disassembly of `strcpy`? Maybe it's pushing registers onto the stack. Probably not though.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any push commands in `strcpy`

Answer (score 8):

A variation of this question is asked every month or so.

The thing is quite simple: Writing over a buffer's boundary leads to **undefined behaviour**, which *might* or *might not* involve a segmentation fault and overwriting any particular structure in memory.

The assumption that you make is that there's a mandatory memory layout that everyone uses, and that's simply not true, even less so with techniques like address space randomization, or compiler optimizations.

Hell, why should a `main` function store a traditional return address? It could probably be very well in-lined in the system-/compiler-/binary format-specific startup code.

If the compiler is clever, it'll even notice that `argv[1]` is only accessed by `strcpy`, which copies it to buffer – and then, considering nothing will access the address space at `argv[1]` anymore after `main`, will simply *not allocate anything for buffer* and simply use `&(argv[1])` instead. And since that is used nowhere, your `main()` would be empty but for the `return 0`, a const expression, and hence the call to main could be replaced with writing 0 to `eax` or whatever your platform uses for return values.

Hate to tell you this, but: aside from pointing out that there can be, in fact, buffer overflows, it only gives something that works on a specific machine with a specific compiler version compiling a specific piece of code with a specific libc for a specific architecture. The result cannot be generalized.

Comment: What information do I need to know about a particular linux system and what compiler flags might I need to use to be able to make sure a cookie-cutter buffer overflow attack will work? I have a test coming up where I need to be able to demonstrate some of the basic memory attacks on C programs like this and all these little particularities are really confusing me. So what's the vital information I need to gather before starting?

Comment: There's no cookie-cutter buffer overflow that always works.With address space randomizations,there's even explicit techniques that battle that.You can of course look at the particular assembly and memory layout that a particular compiler in a particular version with its particular flags generates from particular code and infer possible attack vectors,but really,there's not much cookie-cutting here;from getting a feeling of how compilers work,and then being able to easily figure out what you need to change to trigger harmful things,it's all *methodical* knowledge that you need to learn,not copy

Comment: can't I disable the address space randomizations in gdb for a demonstration?

Comment: yes, you can also use some compiler that has bugs or not use an operating system at all, if it makes your life easier. However, what would be the point of a demonstration? Also, rest assured, this is not randomization taking place, this is just your general memory layout assumption being wrong.

Comment: I know all these things make it less and less real-world scenario, but to be honest I'm just trying to pass this class at the moment. The professor just wants us to be able to show that we understand the basics, not ways around all of the latest security measures. How do I quickly determine the memory layout of the system I'm using?

Comment: Do what you're doing: look at the disassembly and figure out what is where!

Comment: What professor, @Jake?  This is the first you've mentioned about any kind of formal class.  How would being able to replicate video help you pass the class?  It suddenly seems like you've posed an X-Y question.